# Update using one to one relationship hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have one parent object as Employee and child object as Address. I just need to update the both objects using Employee object. But when updating using employee object i just getting emp_id should not be null. Here is my table and entity

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
`employee_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`employee_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`employee_desg` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`salary` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`employee_reference_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Address table

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
`address_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`emp_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`),
KEY `employee_address` (`emp_id`),
CONSTRAINT `employee_address` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `employee`   (`employee_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Employee Object

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NAME")
private String employeeName;

@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_DESG")
private String employeeDesg;

@Column(name = "SALARY")
private String salary;

@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_REFERENCE_ID")
private String employeeReferenceId;

public String getEmployeeReferenceId() {
    return employeeReferenceId;
}

public void setEmployeeReferenceId(String employeeReferenceId) {
    this.employeeReferenceId = employeeReferenceId;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;


public String getEmployeeName() {
    return employeeName;
}

public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
}

public String getEmployeeDesg() {
    return employeeDesg;
}

public void setEmployeeDesg(String employeeDesg) {
    this.employeeDesg = employeeDesg;
}

public String getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(String salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Address Object

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

@Id
@Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "ADDRESS")
private String address;
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER , cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="emp_id",referencedColumnName="employee_id")
private Employee employee;

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}

public Address() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

My code is

```
public class StudentUtil1To1 {
public static void main(String args[]){
    SessionFactory factory=null;
    Configuration configuration=null;
    ServiceRegistry registry=null;
    Session session=null;
    try{
        configuration= new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        registry=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        factory=configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory(registry);
        session= factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();


            Employee emp=new Employee();
            emp.setId(1);
            emp.setEmployeeReferenceId("CP001");
            emp.setEmployeeName("Muthu");
            emp.setEmployeeDesg("Developer");
            emp.setSalary("15000");

            Address address=new Address();
            address.setAddress("3, Civil aerodrome, CBE");


            emp.setAddress(address);
            address.setEmployee(emp);
            session.update(emp);



        System.out.println("Successfuly Saved");
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(session!=null){
            session.close();
        }
        if(factory!=null){
            factory.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the error is

```
09:40:48.815 [http-nio-8081-exec-7] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
09:40:48.816 [http-nio-8081-exec-7] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Column 'emp_id' cannot be null
```

What i need to for update. Correct my mistake.

Comment: show your code to save these entities

Comment: Updated vikram singh

Comment: instead of using update use merge because you are using detached instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already mapped **Address** entity in **employee** entity like this

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
```

You dont have to do same thing in address class means

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER , cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="emp_id",referencedColumnName="employee_id")
private Employee employee;
```

Above code is not required in **address** entity.And **remove** the **employee attribute** from **address class**.
Now you already added the **CascadeType.ALL** in **OneToOne** annotation and save only employee object like this

```
 Employee emp=new Employee();
            Address address=new Address("your address");
            emp.setAddress(address);
            emp.setId(1);
            emp.setEmployeeReferenceId("CP001");
            emp.setEmployeeName("Muthu");
            emp.setEmployeeDesg("Developer");
            emp.setSalary("15000");
            session.update(emp);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.@MapppedBy annotation means：the entity annotationed by @MapppedBy,give up the reference of key，so in the employee table,dont have the column named "address_id".
the relation between Employee and Address controlled by "address" table.
2. when you use [session.update(emp);],you havent have the data of "Employee" table.but emp_id is the FOREIGN KEY,so will occur this problem
3. i can first insert Employee，then [session.update(emp);]